# What is the motorcycle that the Alpha Twins ride?

Tags: object-identification, teen-wolf

Yes, I know that they’re not alpha’s anymore but who cares? That’s what I call them when I get lazy.[image]

Answer (score 4):

They look like they're the **[MV Agusta F3](https://www.mvagusta.com.au/portfolios/f3/)** range, most likely the [675](http://www.mvagusta.com/en/motorcycles/f3-675/) but it could possibly be the [800](http://www.mvagusta.com/en/motorcycles/f3-800/).

[image: Picture of the MV Agusta F3 675 model motorcycle in Black. The bike has a very distinctive diamond shape. The bike's sleek black appearance is complemented by a visible red strut.]  <sup>[img src](http://www.mvagusta.com/en/motorcycles/f3-675/)</sup>

As you can see, the headlight has a very telling shape. The ones used in the show would be an earlier model, given the shape and position of the indicator lights. Perhaps the [F4 750 Serie Oro](http://onlymotorbikes.com/mv-agusta/f4-750-serie-oro/mv-agusta-f4-750-serie-oro-2003-pic-113913.html):

[image]  <sup>[img src](http://onlymotorbikes.com/mv-agusta/f4-750-serie-oro/mv-agusta-f4-750-serie-oro-2003-pic-113913.html)</sup>